# Color picker C# передать цвет в Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет друзья.
Как Мне передать код цвета в контроллер? Хочу хранить цвет в базе данных, дальше уже как нибудь использовать беря из базы данных указаный цвет. Возможно не совсем правильное решение хранить в строке, если кто подскажет более оптимальное решение буду благодарен

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.colorPick = function(config) {

        return this.each(function() {
            new $.colorPick(this, config || {});
        });

    };

    $.colorPick = function (element, options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.colorPick.defaults, options);
        if(options.str) {
            this.options.str = $.extend({}, $.fn.colorPick.defaults.str, options.str);
        }
        $.fn.colorPick.defaults = this.options;
        this.color   = this.options.initialColor.toUpperCase();
        this.element = $(element);

        var dataInitialColor = this.element.data('initialcolor');
        if (dataInitialColor) {
            this.color = dataInitialColor;
            this.appendToStorage(this.color);
        }

        var uniquePalette = [];
        $.each($.fn.colorPick.defaults.palette.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase() }), function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, uniquePalette) === -1) uniquePalette.push(el);
        });

        this.palette = uniquePalette;

        return this.element.hasClass(this.options.pickrclass) ? this : this.init();
    };

    $.fn.colorPick.defaults = {
        'initialColor': '#3498db',
        'paletteLabel': 'Цвета:',
        'allowRecent': true,
        'recentMax': 5,
        'allowCustomColor': false,
        'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1", "#bdc3c7", "#95a5a6", "#7f8c8d"],
        'onColorSelected': function() {
            this.element.css({'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color});
        }
    };

    $.colorPick.prototype = {

        init : function(){

            var self = this;
            var o = this.options;

            $.proxy($.fn.colorPick.defaults.onColorSelected, this)();

            this.element.click(function(event) {
                if (event.target != event.currentTarget){
                    return;
                }

                var offset = $(self.element).offset();

                event.preventDefault();
                self.show(self.element, event.pageX - offset.left, event.pageY - offset.top);

                $('.customColorHash').val(self.color);

                $('.colorPickButton').click(function(event) {
                    self.color = $(event.target).attr('hexValue');
                    self.appendToStorage($(event.target).attr('hexValue'));
                    self.hide();
                    $.proxy(self.options.onColorSelected, self)();
                    return false;
                });
                $('.customColorHash').click(function(event) {
                    return false;
                }).keyup(function (event) {
                    var hash = $(this).val();
                    if (hash.indexOf('#') !== 0) {
                        hash = "#"+hash;
                    }
                    if (/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(hash)) {
                        self.color = hash;
                        self.appendToStorage(hash);
                        $.proxy(self.options.onColorSelected, self)();
                        $(this).removeClass('error');
                    } else {
                        $(this).addClass('error');
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }).blur(function() {
                self.element.val(self.color);
                $.proxy(self.options.onColorSelected, self)();
                self.hide();
                return false;
            });

            $(document).on('click', function(event) {
                if ($.contains(self.element[0], event.target)){
                    return;
                }
                self.hide();
                return true;
            });

            return this;
        },

        appendToStorage: function(color) {
            if ($.fn.colorPick.defaults.allowRecent === true) {
                var storedColors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorPickRecentItems"));
                if (storedColors == null) {
                    storedColors = [];
                }
                if ($.inArray(color, storedColors) == -1) {
                    storedColors.unshift(color);
                    storedColors = storedColors.slice(0, $.fn.colorPick.defaults.recentMax)
                    localStorage.setItem("colorPickRecentItems", JSON.stringify(storedColors));
                }
            }
        },

        show: function(element, left, top) {

            $(".colorPickWrapper").remove();

            $(element).prepend('<div class="colorPickWrapper"><div id="colorPick" style="display:none;top:' + top + 'px;left:' + left + 'px"><span>'+$.fn.colorPick.defaults.paletteLabel+'</span></div></div>');

            jQuery.each(this.palette, function (index, item) {
                $("#colorPick").append('<div class="colorPickButton" hexValue="' + item + '" style="background:' + item + '"></div>');
            });
            if ($.fn.colorPick.defaults.allowCustomColor === true) {
                $("#colorPick").append('<input type="text" style="margin-top:5px" class="customColorHash" />');
            }
            if ($.fn.colorPick.defaults.allowRecent === true) {
                $("#colorPick").append('<span style="margin-top:5px">Recent:</span>');
                if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorPickRecentItems")) == null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorPickRecentItems")) == []) {
                    $("#colorPick").append('<div class="colorPickButton colorPickDummy"></div>');
                } else {
                    jQuery.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorPickRecentItems")), function (index, item) {
                        $("#colorPick").append('<div class="colorPickButton" hexValue="' + item + '" style="background:' + item + '"></div>');
                        if (index == $.fn.colorPick.defaults.recentMax-1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            $("#colorPick").fadeIn(200);
        },

        hide: function() {
            $( ".colorPickWrapper" ).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(".colorPickWrapper").remove();
                return this;
            });
        },

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

create View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUploadedFiles", "TrainingType", FormMethod.Post, new
{ enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @*ColorPic*@
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Picker1)
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" name="Picker1">
                <div class="picker" id="picker1"></div>
                @*ColorPic*@
            </div>
        </div>       
        <script>
            $("#picker1").colorPick({
                'initialColor': '#8e44ad',
                'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                'onColorSelected': function () {
                    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                    this.element.css({ 'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color });
                }
            });
        </script>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

model

```
 public class TrainingTypeViewModel : IEntityBase
    {

        [Display(Name = "Цвет")]
        public string Collor { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public override ActionResult Create(TraningViewModel traningModel)
        {
            traningModel.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            TraningViewModel model = _traningService.getUrl(traningModel);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return base.Create(model);
            }
            return base.Create(traningModel);
        }
```

Comment: передавайте как строку формата `#xxxxxx` или 3-4 значения типа `byte` чтобы получить rgba, в C# есть возможность из строки hex получить цвет `ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#xxxxxx");`

Comment: А как в контроллер передать? Как для базы данных значение? ` <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" name="Picker1">`  Я думаю через hidden но а как Мне в него поместить значение цвета?

Comment: Вы же используете функцию обратного вызова onColorSelected? Так почему бы в ней не вносить/обновлять значение в скрытом поле?

Comment: Я не смог разобраться как через нее сделать, как только не пытался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не смотрел, что находится в Вашем JavaScript коде, но полагаю, что вы получаете какой-то цвет. Вам нужно пометить параметр с помощью атрибута `[Bind("названия во View")]` в методе `Create`

Model:

```
class Palette
{
   public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
   <!-- Заметьте, type="color"!!! По аналогии можно сделать так же через hidden, 
        просто через JavaScript задайте свойство value у вашего <input> -->
   <input type="color" asp-for="Color" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
class PaletteController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Color")] Palette palette)
    {
        if(Model.IsValid)
        {
           //тут ваши действия с palette
        }
        return View(palette);
    }
}
```

Comment: Неплохо, даже без Js  можно. Но Мне бы хотелось используя Мой Js передать цвет в контроллер. `$.fn.colorPick.defaults ` обратите пожалуйста внимания на функцию Js. Можно ли через нее поставить?

Comment: Я не уверен, я только начал изучать asp, но мне кажется самым простым решением запихнуть в `input hidden` и передать в контроллер через `button type=submit`